# Merge three multidimensional array with different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have a little problem for merging 3 multidimensional array with different lengths and with no duplicate key into one array like this:

My 3 arrays:

```
$volume380 = array {
array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-30"
    "VOLUME380" => 813.0
}
    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-31"
    "VOLUME380" => 1188.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-01"
    "VOLUME380" => 1081.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-02"
    "VOLUME380" => 886.0
}
}

$volume320 = array {
array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-30"
    "VOLUME320" => 813.0
}
    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-31"
    "VOLUME320" => 1188.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-02"
    "VOLUME320" => 1081.0
}
}

$volume800 = array {
array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-30"
    "VOLUME800" => 813.0
}
    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-31"
    "VOLUME800" => 1188.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-01"
    "VOLUME800" => 1081.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-02"
    "VOLUME800" => 886.0
}
}
```

Result i want:

```
$volumeTot = array {
array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-30"
    "VOLUME380" => 813.0
    "VOLUME320" => 813.0
    "VOLUME800" => 813.0
}
    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-07-31"
    "VOLUME380" => 1188.0
    "VOLUME320" => 1188.0
    "VOLUME800" => 1188.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-01"
    "VOLUME380" => 1081.0
    "VOLUME800" => 1081.0
}

    array {
    "DATE" => "2018-08-02"
    "VOLUME380" => 886.0
    "VOLUME320" => 1081.0
    "VOLUME800" => 886.0
}
}
```

I have tried different way to figure this out, but due to the different lengths of the array I'm a little bit stucked with this.

I have tried with a for loop and array merge but it does not do what I want.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From seeing your data, it seems "DATE" seems to be the "key" per se.  Considering this logic, the function "array_indexer" converts an existing data point, say like $volume380, to an indexed array using "DATE" as the key for the array.  A second function "array_deindexer" is created to revert the array format to the one your original data appears in.

The merging happens inside the function "array_combiner", which "indexes" both the given new array and the accumulated array, and then combines common keys (as in the "DATE" value).

The full code is given below:

```
$volume380 = array (
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-30",
        "VOLUME380" => 813.0
    ),
        array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-31",
        "VOLUME380" => 1188.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-08-01",
        "VOLUME380" => 1081.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-08-02",
        "VOLUME380" => 886.0
    )
);

$array_final = array_combiner($volume380);

$volume320 = array (
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-30",
        "VOLUME320" => 813.0
    ),
        array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-31",
        "VOLUME320" => 1188.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-08-02",
        "VOLUME320" => 1081.0
    )
);

$array_final = array_combiner($volume320);

$volume800 = array (
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-30",
        "VOLUME800" => 813.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-07-31",
        "VOLUME800" => 1188.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-08-01",
        "VOLUME800" => 1081.0
    ),
    array (
        "DATE" => "2018-08-02",
        "VOLUME800" => 886.0
    )
);

$array_final = array_combiner($volume800);

print_r($array_final);

function array_combiner($array_tmp) {
    global $array_final;
    $array_tmp = array_indexer($array_tmp);
    $tmp = array();
    if (count($array_final) > 0)  {
        $tmp = array_indexer($array_final);
        foreach ($array_tmp as $k1 => $v1) {
            if (!isset($tmp[$k1])) $tmp[$k1] = array();
            foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
                $tmp[$k1][$k2] = $v2;
            }
        }
    } else $tmp = $array_tmp;
    return array_deindexer($tmp);
}

function array_indexer($array_tmp) {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($array_tmp as $k1 => $v1) {
        $index = "";
        $data = array();
        foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
            if ($k2 == "DATE") $index = $v2;
            else $data[$k2] = $v2;
        }
        if (strlen($index) > 0) $tmp[$index] = $data;
    }
    return $tmp;
}

function array_deindexer($array_tmp) {
    $tmp = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array_tmp as $k1 => $v1) {
        $tmp[$i]["DATE"] = $k1;
        foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) $tmp[$i][$k2] = $v2;
        $i++;
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, this is not working it only return me the last array.

Comment: Just use the following line:
$array_final = array_combiner($volume380);   The $array_final will always have the combined final array

Comment: It's working, my problem becoms from fact that array_final was not a global variable and was in a function.

Comment: Oh ok.  In my example code, $array_final is a global variable in the array_combiner function.  Thanks!